# Wordpress, i'm not able to Removes this <li> from Breadcrumbs

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

the pages affected: http://www.love4wellness.it/shop/formula-1-pro/

i tried several ways to remove this unwanted (and wrong)

tag. As you can see from the picture below it's also in a wrong position (over each other).

http://s18.postimg.org/dd6xcnxq1/image.png

It's showing only on category products and single page product of woocommerce.

As you can see the html code maybe the cause.

I searched in my Functions.php file and i found a lot of call to breadcrumb like this:

```
<li typeof="v:Breadcrumb">
```

And tried to change/remove all one by one but nothing change...

Why it's not in normal post too? Or pages? Only in woocommerce related pages? I'm not able to understand very well PHP, i really havo no idea on how to remove this...

Please help :-) I'm being mad

Comment: This is the HTML code http://s28.postimg.org/hxpfghfod/image.png

Comment: Please, when someone give me -1 reputation, please, should specify why? I'm sure in wrong, but if i know why, i should make my life better...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Sometime ago i had accidentally deleted the 'Shop' page. It's a default Woocommerce page and code refer refer to it also if not exist anymore..

Admin, please set this Ask as solved. Thanks and sorry